# Angularjs ctrl unit test failing on dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Trying to figure out why is test failing if there is no check for dependency existence?

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['UserService', '$scope', '$q',  function(userServivce,$scope, $q){
    
  var userCall = userServivce.getUsers(); // working in controller but fail test
  
  //test paasses
  if(userServivce){
    var userCall = userServivce.getUsers()
  }
})
```

Test:

```js
describe('MainCtrl', function () {
  var $scope, userService, $q, MainCtrl;
    
  beforeEach(module('app'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_){
    MainCtrl = _$controller_;
    $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
    MainCtrl('MainCtrl', {$scope: $scope, UserService: userService, $q: $q});
  }));

  it('should scope to be defined', function()  {
   
   expect($scope).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

Angular.js 1.3 KarmaJasmine 
If no if statement getting error:

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'userService.getUsers')
    undefined
    static/js/app/controllers.js:9:2255
    e@static/js/node_modules/angularjs/angular.min.js:36:320

[Karma conf link](http://plnkr.co/edit/AeGv9MmnTkfI1sJdKWWS?p=preview)

Comment: Why have you different names of module in a controller and a test files?

Comment: Ops, thanks :) haven't to copied here the proper file. Just replaced with a proper example.

Comment: Do you use a package `angular-mocks` when testing ?

Comment: yes, will paste a karma.conf in a question body

Comment: Posted link to karma konf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified the variable but haven't defined `userService` property:

```
var $scope, userService, $q, MainCtrl;

userService = {
    getUsers => function() {
        // logic, mock or return here
    }
};
```